# Error when trying to SSH into server using a WSL

Tags: ssh, rsync, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ufw, openssh

I need to obtain data from a server, using my WSL (Ubuntu 20.04) and to do so I run the command

```
rsync -av -e "ssh -vvv -oPort=5822" 'address'
```

where 'address' is of course replaced with the actual address. Doing so results in the following error

```
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving 'adress' port 5822
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 'address' ['ip'] port 5822.
debug1: connect to address 'ip' port 5822: Resource temporarily unavailable
ssh: connect to host 'adress' port 5822: Resource temporarily unavailable
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235) [Receiver=3.1.3]
```

Searching for solutions online originally had me believe that firewall settings caused the issue. However, despite turning off my firewall on windows, and disabling UFW on my WSL, the issue remains.

Is there anything else I should try?

Let me know if you need more information on my setup

Comment: Have you pinged that "address"  from inside and outside of WSL ?

Comment: @ParsaMousavi As a beginner, I wasn't aware that pinging addresses was a thing. Now I went to https://www.ipaddressguide.com/ping, and the ping result mentions 100% packet loss. I guess I can conclude that the issue is not on my side then?

Comment: You can also ping it from your own system . In both linux and windows you can use the "ping" command . And if you're sure that the server is up but you cannot reach it, you can setup a VPN.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi Okay, pinging from Linux and windows gives the same result. I'll look into setting up a VPN and talk to people who will know if the server is having issues. Thanks for your help. If you want to post an actual answer, ill gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If despite turning off your firewall on Windows, and disabling UFW on your WSL, the issue remained, I suggest you install and set up a VPN.

Like, @ParsaMousavi mentioned in the comments above, you can first ping the address from your system, just to be sure you still aren't reaching the server before doing the above.

Hope this looks like an actual answer to your problem!

Answer (score 1):

double check that your addresses are set up correctly from your domain registrar to your box...i had this exact same error and kept overlooking that my addressing (at registrar level) was inconsistent.